# PayPal Pre-Approved Payment Failed

Tags: paypal

I've created a crowd funding site, similar to KickStarter.

Everything is setup, the project finished and it requested the payments via pre-approved payments in PayPal.

There were 6 backers, when requesting the payment via a cron it failed on 4 of them but 2 of them were collected and work perfectly.

I had my own PayPal account as one of the backers, and mine was one that failed. Attached is grab of the pre-approved payment in my paypal account - this has since disappeared which I assume is because the date has passed. ***(EDIT: I can't attach an image)***.

> It has;
>
> Payment Method
>
> Primary funding source - PayPal Account Balance
>
> Backup funding source - Not specified

The thing that stands out is the backup funding, I had no funds in my account but it is linked to my bank/cards etc. It looks the the pre-approved payment was only going to use my PayPal balance which was zero.

I can only assume the other backers that failed were the same, and the ones that were succesful had a PayPal balance.

My question is, how do I specify, from the website point of viewer that all backers need a backup funding source. Surely Kickstarter doesn't have multiple failed payments.

Comment: Hi, this question appears to be off-topic because it is about Paypal rather than programming. It *may* be on topic on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com, but be sure to check their FAQ first.

Comment: Thanks. Technically yes, but I'm not sure if it's my programming, am I not sending/pulling the correct data in my PHP or if it's a PayPal issue?